# error: unknown type name 'V' in C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct

I checked other answers but they didn't work for me, I am getting error: unknown type name 'V' in my C++ code while using struct. I am unable to decipher why this error is occurring, please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcahL.png)

Comment: Please avoid pasting code as a linked image, paste it inline ... and code that **does** things, rather than **declares** things cannot be given in the global scope

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to execute statements at global scope.  C++ doesn't allow that.  You need to put your code inside a function.

Comment: Thanks for your response John. I've now initialized V.m & I.m inside main() function.     
Now the error changed                                                                                                    
:!g++ -o fib_lnn fib_lnn.cpp                                                                                                                           
fib_lnn.cpp:34:11: error: expected expression
    V.m = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}};
          ^
fib_lnn.cpp:35:11: error: expected expression
    I.m = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
          ^
2 errors generated.

shell returned 1

Comment: @sumanth: Please post a new question if you still need help.  Include the code as text in the question, do not post code as images.